# (0xC000041D error) при выходе из скрипта

Tags: windows-10, tkinter, python-3.6, pywin32

*Вводная: windows 10 (x64), python 3.6, pyCharm 3.2(CE), pypiwin32(220), tkinter*

Пишу небольшой скрипт для получения дескриптора окна с последующим обращением к нему, в принципе всё нормально работает кроме одного момента, если закрыть гуи виндовым "крестиком" программа выпадает с:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)

Если дать программе полностью выполнить код, она сама закроет гуи без ошибок.

Методом перебора выяснил что ошибку вызывает модуль *win32ui*, но он нужен.

Код скрипта с примером работы:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import win32gui, win32con, win32ui

#processListReturn[0] - hwnd
#processListReturn[1] - title
def gui_finder():

    processList = []
    processListTitle = []
    processListReturn= []


    def start_parsing(event):
        processListReturn.append(processList[processList.index(comboboxValues.get())-1])
        processListReturn.append(processList[processList.index(comboboxValues.get())])
        wProcessWin.quit()

    def window_callback(hwnd, n):
        title = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        if title != '' and win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            processList.append(hwnd)
            processList.append(title)
            processListTitle.append(title)

    def quit():
        wProcessWin.destroy()
        sys.exit()

    wProcessWin = Tk()
    wProcessWin.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quit)
    wProcessWin.geometry('234x78')
    wProcessWin.resizable(width='false', height='false')
    wProcessWin.title('finderGui')
    Label(text='Select windows:').place(x=6, y=0)
    win32gui.EnumWindows(window_callback, None)
    comboboxValues = StringVar()
    Combobox(wProcessWin, textvariable=comboboxValues, value=processListTitle, width=33).place(x=6, y=20)
    wButton = Button(wProcessWin, text='Start', width=14)
    wButton.bind("<Button-1>", start_parsing)
    wButton.place(x=134, y=47)
    wProcessWin.mainloop()
    wProcessWin.destroy()

    return processListReturn


def screen(hwnd, path="screenshot.png"):
    left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    w = right - left
    h = bot - top

    wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
    cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()

    dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, w, h)

    cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
    cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (w, h), dcObj, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)

    dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, path)

    dcObj.DeleteDC()
    cDC.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())


test = gui_finder()
screen(test[0])
```

Буду благодарен за наводки, куда мне копать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось это баг совместимости tkinter и win32ui. 
Багрепорт на sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/636/

Ответ:

> Sadly Tkinter and win32ui have played poorly together, in various
>   ways, basically forever. This is just the nature of the beast when
>   multiple things want to control the main event loop. I've no intention
>   of trying to fix this, but would accept patches that make things suck
>   less then they currently do.